Type of Union or Union of Types
In Python, is Type[Union[A, B, C]] the same as Union[Type[A], Type[B], Type[C]]?
I think they are equivalent, and the interpreter seems to agree.
ChatGPT (which, from my past experience, tends to be wrong with this type of questions) disagrees so I was wondering which one is more correct.
To be clear: I want a union of the types of A, B or C, not a union of instances of A, B or C. The first option is shorter and IMHO more readable.
In other words, given these definitions:
class A: pass
class B: pass
class C: pass

def foo(my_class: Type[Union[A, B, C]]): pass

I expect this usage to be correct:
foo(A)   # pass the class A itself

But not this one:
foo(A()) # pass an instance of A


In this specific context I am forced to use a Python version that doesn't support the newer A | B | C union syntax.

Note that "yes" answer to this question does not generalize: while type is distributive over union, e.g. list[A | B] is not the same as list[A] | list[B]

I know, but it's a good addition in case someone reaches this question looking for something similar. Thanks!

That these two are equivalent is technically an "implementation detail" (even though all major type checkers are treating them this way): The specification has yet to note such a relation. I have proposed that it be added, in case you care.

They are the same. You can use reveal_type and check.
class A: ...
class B: ...
class C: ...

def something(a: type[A | B | C]) -> None:
    reveal_type(a)

def something_else(b: type[A] | type[B]| type[C]) -> None:
    reveal_type(b)

mypy main.py
main.py:6: note: Revealed type is "Union[type[main.A], type[main.B], type[main.C]]"
main.py:9: note: Revealed type is "Union[type[main.A], type[main.B], type[main.C]]"

pyright main.py 
  main.py:6:17 - information: Type of "a" is "type[A] | type[B] | type[C]"
  main.py:9:17 - information: Type of "b" is "type[A] | type[B] | type[C]"

Edit:
Older syntax
from typing import Union, Type
class A: ...
class B: ...
class C: ...

def something(a: type[A | B | C]) -> None:
    reveal_type(a)

def something_else(b: type[A] | type[B]| type[C]) -> None:
    reveal_type(b)

def old_something(c: Type[Union[A, B, C]]) -> None:
    reveal_type(c)

def old_something_else(d: Union[Type[A], Type[B], Type[C]]) -> None:
    reveal_type(d)

mypy main.py
main.py:7: note: Revealed type is "Union[type[main.A], type[main.B], type[main.C]]"
main.py:10: note: Revealed type is "Union[type[main.A], type[main.B], type[main.C]]"
main.py:13: note: Revealed type is "Union[type[main.A], type[main.B], type[main.C]]"
main.py:16: note: Revealed type is "Union[type[main.A], type[main.B], type[main.C]]"

pyright main.py
  main.py:7:17 - information: Type of "a" is "type[A] | type[B] | type[C]"
  main.py:10:17 - information: Type of "b" is "type[A] | type[B] | type[C]"
  main.py:13:17 - information: Type of "c" is "type[A] | type[B] | type[C]"
  main.py:16:17 - information: Type of "d" is "type[A] | type[B] | type[C]"


As an aside, I wonder which one is more readable to people that are not me.

@noamtm I would probably prefer the one I used on something as its shorter, but if you really want to express readability, I would rather add a type alias

For this task I'm stuck with a Python version that doesn't support the new Union syntax, so my variant is more like your old_something.
